# check for time duration during loop

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am using MBProgressHUD to display a progress indicator. The delegate that is called when the indicator is shown is:

```
- (void)myTask {
    while (self.show_progress == NO){

    }
}
```

basically when it goes out of the loop it dismisses the indicator. Now the issue is that I would like do something more in this method. I would like to check for how long has the indicator been spinning for, if it has been more than 5 seconds then I would like to re-load the request. The question is how do I check for this?

This is just to prevent the apps waiting for an infinite amount of time just in case the response never got back or got stuck somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, your code just waits until the property `show_progress` becomes `NO`. I don't know why your code does this, it seems a little inelegant. If you want to keep it this way, at least use a condition lock to prevent the 100% CPU usage:

Prepare the condition lock like this:

```
NSConditionLock *progressLock = [[NSConditionLock alloc] initWithCondition:0];
```

In your second thread, once your loading stuff or whatever finishes, change the condition like this:

```
[progressLock lock];
[progressLock unlockWithCondition:1];
```

And in your method, do this:

```
- (void)myTask {
    NSDate *timeoutDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:5];
    if ([progressLock lockWhenCondition: 1 beforeDate:timeoutDate) {
        // we aquired the lock, processing has finished
        [progressLock unlock];
    } else {
        // we didn't aquire the lock because the 5 seconds have passed
        // reload the request or do whatever you want to do
    }
}
```

This method waits 5 seconds, and then times out. It uses no CPU in those 5 seconds, because it waits for a signal at the lockWhenCondition:beforeDate: call.

Comment: before I make a request/ie, showing the progress I need to lock it again or do what?

Comment: Just call `[progressLock lock]; [progressLock unlockWithCondition:0];` to reset the lock back to the initial state if you do a second request.

Comment: that will be the same condition as the first time it was initialized ([[NSConditionLock alloc] initWithCondition:0];) ?

Comment: yes. the "condition" is just a number. I choose `0` to mean loading and `1` to mean finished.

Comment: I sometimes get this message int he log *** -[NSConditionLock unlock]: lock (<NSConditionLock: 0x7bc17d0> '(null)') unlocked when not locked
2011-05-30 23:13:41.378 Cvore[1056:952b] *** Break on _NSLockError() to debug.

Comment: You always pair the calls to `-lock` and `-unlock`. But if you do a call like `-lockWhenCondition:beforeDate`, you can only unlock if you actually aquired the lock. Also, make sure that locking and unlocking always occurs in the same thread (required), and if possible inside the same method (not required, but easier)

Comment: Also see the section about thread safety and different kinds of locks in the Apple developer reference  [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/ThreadSafety/ThreadSafety.html) for more information.

Comment: ok, I think I fixed it. Just a clarification, basically before making a request I do [progressLock lock]; [progressLock unlockWithCondition:0], when the request is finish I call [progressLock lock];
[progressLock unlockWithCondition:1];, is this correct?

Comment: Exactly. And sometime in between `-myTask` calls `-lockWhenCondition:` to wait for the request to complete.

Comment: what if I didn't get any response back and I just want to lock it back? do I need to do anything?

Comment: if you don't get any response, it's condition will still be 0. No need to do anything. But you probably have to somehow make sure that the first request is cancelled before you start the second request, otherwise you might end up with all kind of weird problems.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with MBProgressHUD , but on general terms you could do the following:

When you first make the request do:

```
NSDate *startTime = [NSDate date];
```

Then whenever you want to check how long has it been:

```
NSTimeInterval timePassed = -[startTime timeIntervalSinceNow];
```

`timePassed` will have the value, in seconds, of how long has it been since you made your request. May be you should consider using NSTimer for this: Schedule a timer that will fire 5 seconds after you performed your request, if it triggers cancel the request but if you receive a response before the timer triggers invalidate the timer.

Comment: Definitely do anything but hog the entire UI thread doing a busy wait. `dispatch_after()` could be used to handle restarting after 5 seconds just fine, and is likely to be cleaner than an `NSTimer` (no new object reference to manage and no need to add a callback method).

Answer (score 0):

The way I've gone about similar situations is to set up a timer.  The basic concept would be to start the timer when the indicator starts spinning.  Then invalidate it when the indicator stops.  Else if it goes on for 5 seconds, execute your method.

So in your header, you'll want

```
NSTimer *myTimer;
```

then in the implementation, when you start the indicator spinning,

```
[indicator startAnimating];
if (myTimer != nil) {
    [myTimer invalidate];
    myTimer = nil;
}
myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0 target:self selector:@selector(reloadRequest) serInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```

when you stop the indicator from spinning, send `[myTimer invalidate];` and `myTimer = nil;`.  If the specified time is reached beforehand, reload the request in your `reloadRequest` method